# how to highlight a selected item from a repeater while clicking on that item that is navigating to other page there the item should highlighted

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In a visual web part i am using a repeater control and the items are pages while clicking on that item that will navigates to another page in that page also i am placing the same web part. Now my requirement is while navigating to the page the selected page item should be highlighted. I implement the below code, so please suggest what to add this.

Thanks in advance.

ascx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrPages" runat="server">
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        |
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnUrl" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("url")%>' Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'
    runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

ascx.cs code:

```
foreach (SPListItem page in Pages)
{
    DataRow dr;
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["url"] = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + folder.Url + "/" + page.Name;
    string[] pagename = page.Title.ToString().Split('.');
    dr["Name"] = pagename[0];
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
rptrPages.DataSource = dt;
rptrPages.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

    if (SPContext.Current.Item["Title"].ToString() == dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString())
        {
        LinkButton Link1 = (LinkButton)rptrPages.Items[i].FindControl("lbtnUrl");
        Link1.Attributes["OnClick"] = "return false";
        Link1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        string url = dt.Rows[i]["url"].ToString();
        LinkButton Link1 = (LinkButton)rptrPages.Items[i].FindControl("lbtnUrl");
        Link1.PostBackUrl = url;
    }
}
```